# Blender Model is incorrectly rendered in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx, blender, 3d-model

I am having trouble rendering a model in libGdx.
I have created a simple car model in blender but, when i render it in libGdx, it renders incorrectly.
This is what it looks in blender(how it is supposed to look):
[image]

This is how it looks in libGdx:

[image]

As you can see, the wheels are all pointing the wrong direction which doesn't make sense as i am not turning them at all.

It works when there is only 1 object in the model but when i add more objects such as the wheels, this happens.

Here is my create() method:

```
public void create () {
    camera=new PerspectiveCamera(67,800,480);
    camera.position.set(0f, 0f, 20f);
    camera.lookAt(0f, 0f, 0f);
    camera.near=1f;
    camera.far=100f;

    batch=new ModelBatch();
    builder=new ModelBuilder();

    UBJsonReader jsonreader=new UBJsonReader();
    G3dModelLoader modelloader=new G3dModelLoader(jsonreader);
    cubemodel=modelloader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("carmodel.g3db", Files.FileType.Internal));
    cube=new ModelInstance(cubemodel,0,0,0);


    environment=new Environment();
    environment.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight,0.65f,0.65f,0.65f,1f));


}
```

Here is my render() Method:

```
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    camera.update();
    batch.begin(camera);
    batch.render(cube, environment);
    batch.end();
    camera.rotateAround(new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f), new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f), 0.5f);
}
```

Here is my model:
[carmodel.g3db](https://www.dropbox.com/s/exxhmtr9g9lpxn1/carmodel.g3db?dl=0)

If you need anything else then ask and i will post it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You camera's far/near ratio is 10,000! Reduce that to something less error prone, like 100.

Comment: @Xoppa already tried and it didn't work. I used near 10 and far 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I used Blender, but these are the settings I used to get the model orientation to match in LibGDX. This sets it up so if you use the same orientation and position for your LibGDX camera as your Blender camera, the scenes will be identical.

1. Create your model(s) normally. Save the Blender file.
2. Rotate each model about its center by 90 degrees about the +X axis and apply the transformation.
3. Export the model(s) -Z forward and Y up.
4. Don't save the Blender file because you might want to further change the models in the original orientation.

Comment: I apologize if my question seemed vague, the orientation of the model is not the problem. The model orientation is fine. The problem is that the model is  not rendered properly.

Comment: Ok, then it looks like your model's normals are inverted.

Comment: oh, could you tell me how to invert them again so that they are normal? Thank you so much, I was wondering what the problem was for over a day now.

Comment: In Blender, you can select all the faces and find the button on the left menus to flip or invert normals. (Don't remember what they call it.) There's some option to view normals so you can see which way they are pointing in Blender. If they are pointing inward, lighting will not be correct.

Comment: That worked! Thank you sooo much! i have been struggling with that for a long time now.